# how to attach javascript counter to field in form

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I have a form im making in Adobe DC I want it to count a new number in a field each time the doc is opened it will start with A1 then once its opened it would be A2 and so on. However i cant figure out how to attach the code to a box? Im assuming I need to create a box with the Field named Counter but I cant figure how how to do this in adobe CD

```
var f = this.getField("counter");
f.value = Number(f.value)A+1;
f.defaultValue = f.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

tools > prepare form > create a field > name it counter